Applying Functions across a Row
I have this dataset :
set.seed(123)  
old <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:10, NA), 35, replace = TRUE), ncol = 7, nrow = 5))

In each row, I want to find the first 5 non-NA values and put them into a new dataframe.
I thought about how to do this with the following function:
extract_non_na <- function(row) {
    non_na_values <- na.omit(row)
    if (length(non_na_values) < 5) {
        non_na_values <- c(non_na_values, rep(NA, 5 - length(non_na_values)))
    }
    return(non_na_values[1:5])
}

The problem now was how to apply this function across rows in R. I looked into this and apparently this is done with t?
new <- t(apply(old, 1, extract_non_na))

Is this the correct protocol?

Hi farrow90, looks like your code does what's expected and nicely uses apply and t at that. (Note that in R you need not explicitly return the result of a function's last line.)

If you would like to have row-wise actions, you can use apply like below
> data.frame(t(apply(old, 1, \(x) x[order(is.na(x))][1:5])))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3 10  9 10  4
2  3  5  9  7  1
3 10  4  5  9 10
4  2  6  3  3  9
5  6  9  8  3  5

Or, you can try order + row like below
> data.frame(matrix(unlist(old)[order(row(old), is.na(old))], nrow = nrow(old), byrow = TRUE))[1:5]
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  3 10  9 10  4
2  3  5  9  7  1
3 10  4  5  9 10
4  2  6  3  3  9
5  6  9  8  3  5

